# Adding widget resizing feature to Configurable Map Viewer?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

Is there any way of adding a widget resizing feature or implementing it?

I noticed that the layer widget for example expands according to the number of layers inside it, this can be used to implement widget resizing.

Comment: There are many configurable map viewers - could you provide the link to the one your using?

Comment: @ew_gis: The question is tagged for [CMV](http://cmv.io/] an open source project of which I am one of the developers. For reasons that I am not aware of, a gis.stackexchange.com admin created the "configurable-map-viewer" [tag] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/configurable-map-viewer/info) and made cmv a synonym tag. The new tag does make it less obvious and I would argue they should be reversed. Hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the CMV widgets sitting in the sidebar pane act like the legend widget are thus do resize. They are dojo titlePane widgets which resizes to the inside content does by default. Some widgets might use css to explicitly set the height of the widget but that is optional and may not be necessary. If you have a widget that is not expanding to its full height or width, the first thing I would check is css that is constraining it to a certain size. That's about all the guidance we can provide without some example code demonstrating a specific issue.

Comment: The question was targeted towards the manual resizing feature of the widget similar to ARCGIS for Flex where I'd click and drag from the lower right corner to expand/shrink the widget, I'm not sure if that's doable currently in CMV

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code for the street view widget, this implements a resizable panel when in floating mode.